# "Big Question" slide in beamer (Malmoe)

Tags: beamer, formatting

I'm using Malmoe, but this should be a general question. Typically, when I set a title for a slide, it gets special formatting. In Malmoe, that would be big, blue and fat.

Say I want to have a slide where I only put one sentence in the center (A three liner question), and I want to have it the properties of that slide question - what would be an easy approach?

Alternatively, maybe these style classes come with a special "bigAndIMportant" marker that one can use in slides - but quick research hasn't shown anything like this.

In any way, I would like the sentence to be both vertical and horizontal centered.

Does anyone know more on this issue?

**Update**

So here is some simple mockup:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk
\documentclass{beamer}    
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\begin{document}   
\begin{frame}{The Question}
Here is the question. It is so long that it will be broken over 2-3 lines when it is displayed big. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to emphasize the central text, such that it looks more "eye jumping" than normal text. However, I don't want to break the style. Maybe there is an attribut inside Malmoe (or beamer in general) that one can use for this? Or perhaps a way to make it look similar to the frame title ("The Question") - but it should still be distinguishable..

Comment: `\begin{frame}[plain,c]` is a good start, then to make your text stand out you could use a `beamercolorbox`. Are you looking for advice on the TeXnical side or on the design of the slides? Having a mockup of your desired output and what you accomplished so far would help us help you.

Comment: I don't have a special idea on desired output, just want the text to be more eye jumpy and central. If there's a preset layout for that, I'd take that. Updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is very vague, almost anything would seem to fit the bill.

What about this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}

\newcommand{\questionframe}[2]{
    \frame[c,plain]{
        \centering\huge
        \textbf{\structure{#1}}
        \par\bigskip
        #2
    }
}
\begin{document}
\questionframe{Here is the question?}{And corresponding explanation}
\end{document}
```

The only `beamer`-relevant parts are:

1. `plain` is a frame option removing the navigation bars leaving more space for the question
2. `c` is a frame option forcing centered vertical alignment (just in case you chenge the default globally)
3. `\structure` typesets the text using the color used by the theme for structure elements such as frame titles.